# Unable to execute HQL update query using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, orm

I have 2 entity classes BatchFile and BatchFileRecord. While running the HQL query it gives the following error:

**org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: IsValidated of: com.cc.myApp.dal.models.BatchFileRecord**

```
Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
sess.beginTransaction();
String sb="update BatchFile bf set bf.isCheck = 0 where bf.Id in(selectb.BatchFileId from BatchFileRecord b where b.BatchId = "+batchId+" and b.IsValidated = 0) and bf.BatchId = "+batchId;
    Query query = sess.createQuery(sb);
    int numUpdated = query.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("Rows affected: " + numUpdated);
```

It works well using mysql directly but it doesnt works using hibernate, How can i help myself runnimg this? or is there any alternative way to do so?

Comment: This looks like a hybrid between HQL and pure SQL.  Can you include the entity classes in your question?

Comment: you must use attribute name of your entity class instead of column name of your DB table when you are using entity manager.

Answer (score 0):

IsValidated with first characted in uppercase doesnt match the java bean standard.
Please change the property name or change the getter to getIsvalidated()

Comment: can you post your BatchFile bean class with getters and setters